# How to create a multi-line Text Box like PowerShell in C

Tags: c, powershell, textbox

In PowerShell you can define Classes or Functions in a Multi-line GUI like Text Box. But the stuff actually happens in a console Window. It gives you full controls of multi-line Text Editing. I just want to create that kind of text box in console in C/C++. Does Win32 API have a procedure/function for it? any Code? or any Library? Any hint or lead will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not such thing as C/C++. Pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below with wrapping:

```
pragma once
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
#include "SDLUtils.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Textbox
{
public:
    Textbox(int w, int h, int xPos, int yPos);
    ~Textbox(void);
    void draw();
    void edit(string s);
private:
    TTF_Font *font;
    int width;
    int height;
    Point pos;
    SDL_Surface *textSurface;
    SDL_Color textColor;
    std::string str;
    int maxCharsPerLine;
    int currentLine;
    std::vector<std::string> lines; 
};
```

**CPP**

```
#include "Textbox.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Textbox::Textbox(int w, int h, int xPos, int yPos)
{
    TTF_Init();
    font = TTF_OpenFont("DOTMATRI.ttf", 20);
    textColor.r = 255;
    textColor.g = 0;
    textColor.b = 0;

    width = w;
    height = h;

    pos.x = xPos;
    pos.y = yPos;

    int x, y;
    TTF_SizeText(font,"a",&x,&y);
    cout << "width: " << x << endl;
    cout << "height: " << y << endl;

    maxCharsPerLine = width / x;

    str = "";
    lines.push_back(str);
    currentLine = 0;
}

Textbox::~Textbox(void)
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    TTF_Quit();
}

void Textbox::draw()
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = pos.x;
    rect.y = pos.y;
    rect.w = width;
    rect.h = height;

    SDL_FillRect(SDL_GetVideoSurface(), &rect, SDL_MapRGB(SDL_GetVideoSurface()->format, 100, 100, 0));


    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, lines[i].c_str(), textColor);
        applySurface(pos.x, pos.y, textSurface, SDL_GetVideoSurface());
        pos.y += 21;
    }

    pos.y = 200;
}

void Textbox::edit(string s)
```

Reference LINK : [Creating TextBox](http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/creating-textbox-line-wrapping-733759.html)

Comment: @Freyr99: np. Enjoy coding